# using cprofile with input files

Tags: python, input, cmd, cprofile

I am supposed to run following command for an assignment to analyze the functions in rsa.py

`python -m cProfile -s time rsa.py < tests/1verdict32.in`

I am assuming this file uses tests/1verdict32.in as in the input file to rsa.py.
but I am not familiar with how **cProfile** works with a file as an input
can someone explain to me how this is supposed to work? especially what is the relevance of "<" character in the above line?

ps: the directory structure is

`WD/
 -rsa.py
 -hello.py
 -tests/
      -1verdict_32.in`

also when I run above command, it gives "system cannot find the file specified" error
but the profiler works when I use it on file hello.py
i.e. for the command: `python -m cProfile -s time hello.py`

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo.

Your file is `1verdict_32.in`, and you're attempting to pass in `1verdict32.in`, without the underscore. That's why your shell complains.

Beyond that, `< ...` is a simple shell redirection operator; it means that the shell (bash, zsh, fish, cmd, ...) opens the file `...` and writes it into the process's standard input (in Python, that's `sys.stdin`).